# App Scripts replace string in Google Doc with new list items at same level without changing list style

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a long list in a Google doc in a similar style to this:

> 1. Section 1
>
> 1.1. Apple
>
> 1.2. Banana
>
> 1.3. Pear
>
> 2. Section 2
>
> 2.1. Cat
>
> 2.2. Dog
>
> 2.3. Rabbit
>
> 3. Section 3
>
> 3.1. Rain
>
> 3.2. Snow
>
> 3.3. Thunder

The style is the third one in Google Docs:

[image]

I want to be able to replace any of the second/third/first level list items with a string (e.g. {{ReplaceMe}} ) and run a script which will replace this item and continue adding new list items under this one from an array.

I used a solution from another Stack Overflow answer to add the following two functions:

```
function findListItemWithText(text, doc, body) {
  var index = -1;

  for (var i=0; i<body.getNumChildren(); i++) {
    var child = body.getChild(i);

    if (child.getType() ==  DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) {

      var listItem = child.asListItem();
      if (listItem.getText() == text) {
         index = i;
      }
    }
  }
  return index;
}
```

and

```
function replaceListItem (placeholder, list, doc, body) {

  var index = findListItemWithText(placeholder, doc, body);
  var listItem = body.getChild(index).asListItem();

  // replace the text in the placeholder ListItem
  listItem.setText(list[0]);

  // append the rest of the list after the placeholder ListItem
  for (var i=1; i<list.length; i++) {
    body.insertListItem(index + i, list[i]);  
  }
}
```

I then call this function when creating the document, passing the document references, string to replace, and array:

```
replaceListItem("{{ReplaceMe}}", listItemsArray, doc, body);
```

This gives a solution which almost works, however there are 2 flaws:

(a) This changes the style of my list in the whole document to the default (1. 2. a. b. i. ii. etc); and

(b) Whilst the first array item is added correctly, the next ones appear to be at the previous list level but still indented correctly (i.e. the first may be in level 2 and item c. but then the rest continue the parent level i.e. 3. 4. etc but indented to match the a. b. c. level).

I would like to be able to add a string to replace anywhere in a list and at any level and have this function add to it so that I can call it as required to alter lists in the document.

**EDIT**

[Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/15V87CF8m8g_dD7YEcGGZBFYyGYx2L1PHEWJKpinwAzQ/edit?usp=sharing)'s a rudimentary version of the document.

Here's the list before running the script:

[image]

Here's the script in full edited for this example:

```
function findListItemWithText(text, doc, body) {
  var index = -1;

  for (var i=0; i<body.getNumChildren(); i++) {
    var child = body.getChild(i);

    if (child.getType() ==  DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) {

      var listItem = child.asListItem();
      if (listItem.getText() == text) {
         index = i;
      }
    }
  }
  return index;
}
function replaceListItem (placeholder, list, doc, body) {

  var index = findListItemWithText(placeholder, doc, body);
  var listItem = body.getChild(index).asListItem();

  // replace the text in the placeholder ListItem
  listItem.setText(list[0]);

  // append the rest of the list after the placeholder ListItem
  for (var i=1; i<list.length; i++) {
    body.insertListItem(index + i, list[i]);  
  }
}

function replaceText() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();

  var replacementItems = ["Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"];

  replaceListItem("{{ReplaceMe}}", replacementItems, doc, body);
}
```

Here's the outcome I get:

[image]

And here's the outcome I'm looking for:

[image]

Comment: It would be beneficial if you could share your doc file for the community members to be able to properly replicate the issue & to better visualize it. Also, please share an image/screenshot of the current issue & and your desired result.

Comment: @IrvinJayG. - I've added these details for reference :)

Comment: It looks like this related to an active bug about List Item losing their formatting after an apps script run at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36762602 as I can also replicate the behavior on my end. You may also want to star the bug to get direct email updates or post a comment on the bug report.

Comment: @IrvinJayG. thanks; I've starred it and added a comment that it appears to be experienced with insertListItem() also. Can you confirm that, but for the bug, the code should operate to produce the expected result? And if so whether there is any alternative to this to produce the expected result?